# memory allocation of calling methods, storing local variables and storing created new objects

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, heap-memory, stack-memory

In .NET framework, the local variables, return address and calling methods are stored in **STACK**. Similarly, any objects created is stored in **HEAP**. Now I've some
questions like,

1. How is **QUEUE** implemented in **.NET** framework?
2. **In another languages like C++, JAVA, how are the above conditions addressed**?

Comment: This doesn't answer all of your questions, but it will explain to you that your understanding of how things work in .NET is ... not entirely correct. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail-part-one/

Comment: Also, the generic `Queue<T>` class in .NET is a reference object. Space for it is allocated on the heap. You can see the implementation details yourself here: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/generic/queue.cs,aa3beab99b2e0db2

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Please can any one tell me how the above conditions are handled in JAVA/C++. Also, how is QUEUE data structure used in .NET framework, is QUEUE used to store any variables etc. Thanks!